# How to specify Python interpreter version in VIM?

Tags: python, c++, vim, plugins, autocomplete

In order to write C++ in Vim with plugin, Clang_complete.
After installing, this error occurs:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>14_ClangCompleteInit..<SNR>14_initClangCompletePython:
clang_complete: No python support available.
Cannot use clang library
Compile vim with python support to use libclang
```

But my vim supports both python and python3. `+python/dyn  +python3/dyn`
then I check my python interpreter:

```
:echo has('python')      # output is 0
:echo has('python3')     # output is 1
```

So, I think the reason is my vim dynamic load python3 interpreter by default.
Can I change python interpreter? or set default dynamic load version of python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't want to (or at least should not) set `python3` as the default python interpreter for vim, as then some (most of) your plugins will become incompatible, such as `YouCompleteMe` and `clang_complete` itself, because they do not have `python3` support. Normally plugins that do support `python3` let you decide if you want to use it by adding to your `.vimrc`

```
let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = 'python3'
```

**Solution:** the `:echo has('python')` showing `0` is actually telling you that vim is perhaps not compiled with `python2`. So first check the output of `vim --version` and you should be able to see a list of shared libraries that your compiler has built vim against. Do you see the following? (e.g. for python 2.7):

```
-L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython2.7
```

If not (or if you see both `-lpython2.x` and `-lpython3.x`  I suggest you compile vim from source, linking it specifically to `-lpython2.x`. It is not that difficult to build vim from source. First make sure to remove all your current vim installation, for instance using `aptitude` you'd do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vim vim-runtime vim-gnome vim-tiny vim-common vim-gui-common
```

clone vim mercurial

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/vim/
cd vim
```

and then run `./configure` with the following flags:

```
 ./configure --with-features=huge \
        --enable-cscope \
        --enable-pythoninterp \
        --enable-largefile \
        --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config
```

you might also want to link against `ruby` and `lua` if you want, and then finally run

```
make build
make install
```

[Here](https://github.com/romeric/scripts/blob/master/install_vim.sh) is shell script that will automate the whole process for you. This might be a bit of an overkill, but I think this is how you should handle this to not run with compatibility issues with your future packages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I re compile my vim
my problem is solved.
but I has another question, what `+python/dyn  +python3/dyn` means,

Comment: Doesn't it means that i can use py or py3 command in vim?
( remark: I check my original vim version, it do not have `-L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython2.7` actually.)

Comment: That means that vim is dynamically linking to both `python2` and `python3` but was not specifically compiled with python flag or choosing `python3` by default. This can happen if you install vim using `sudo apt-get install vim`. I might be wrong but having vim installed this way may not actually show compiler flags.

Answer (score 1):

```
" .gvimrc

let &pythonthreedll='C:\...\python37.dll'
let &pythonthreehome='C:\...\Python37'
```

check:

```
:py3 print('hello')
```

and VIM should be matched as the Python (I mean 64, 32 bit)

[windows vim x64 download](https://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/x64/)

Comment: This only works if vim has been compiled with `+python3/dyn` feature