# Change python version vim uses

Tags: python, vim, youcompleteme

I have "YouCompleteMe" plugin in vim, when I activate my virtualenv and enter vim, YouCompleteMe complains about python3.

When I run:

```
vim --version
```

[image]

The "+" icon is beside python3, I need to make it use "python". What is the command to switch this or whats involved?

Comment: Good question. Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114378/how-to-specify-python-interpreter-version-in-vim), though?

Comment: You need to recompile Vim.

Comment: You need to use a vim that's compiled with Python2 or you need to use a youcompleteme version that works with Python3.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to run the install.py script with python3 when compiling YCM.
You may have your default python env set to use python2.

`python3 install.py`