# Terminal and vim file show different python paths and versions

Tags: python, bash, vim, pip

When I check for python version in vim file, it displays 3.6 whereas it shows python 3.7 when I check from the bash terminal. As a result, when I `pip install <somemodule>` from the terminal, it installs in the python 3.7 path. So, when I run my python vim file, the package isn't detected.

How do I change the python vim file to point at the same python version as my Bash terminal does?

**EDIT:** I don't have the sudo command privileges.

**EDIT 2:** I've installed a python 3.7 environment with `conda create -n <env_name> python=3.7` and later `source activate env`.

But, when I now try to `pip install <somemodule>`, it displays message of requirements already satisfied, but the path where the module is in a different env. How to pip install the modules so that they appear in the site-packages of my current <env_name> ?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114378/how-to-specify-python-interpreter-version-in-vim , kind of like what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify Python interpreter version in VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114378/how-to-specify-python-interpreter-version-in-vim)

Comment: @jeremysprofile No, actually. The answer there uses sudo command.